# Playing DRM content using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

If I attached a FairPlay content key using AVSampleBufferAttachContentKey to my CMSampleBuffer, can I then render it using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer

Comment: What happens if you try? Is there an error message you want to ask about?

Comment: I will have to write a demuxer for ts segments to even try it. So just wanted to see if this is even possible without going down that path